# Promise.getNewLibraryCopy() across iframe

Tags: promise, bluebird

I'm creating a multi iframe application on browser. And I want to use `bluebird.js` on each frame. To shorten the load time, I will do the folloings:

First, load bluebird.js on top frame.

Second, on each frame, run the following code:

```
window.Promise = top.Promise.getNewLibraryCopy();`
```

My question is that 'the above code is valid usage of `getNewLibraryCopy()`?'.

I have already tried it, and it works well.
But I want to know 'Is it valid usage?, Is it the intended usage?'.

The [API reference](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.getnewlibrarycopy.html) does not say across iframe.

Comment: Why not just `window.Promise = top.Promise`?

Comment: The reason for use of getNewLibraryCopy is the error message handler. I want to output window.name for unhandled rejection: </br>
 <pre> Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(e, promise) {
    console.log(window.name, e.message, e.stack);
});</pre>

Comment: Sure, then go for it. A possible source of problems might be the scheduler though, it uses `top.setImmediate` (or whatever). Not sure how that behaves with multiple frames.

Comment: "*To shorten the load time*", sending the proper cache headers with the script file and loading it multiple times should be enough though and is probably simpler.

Comment: My application works on embedded device, it is required fastaer startup. But my method mentioned above may have problems potentially. I will load bluebird.js on each iframe. Thanks.